# How to run tomcat catalina script on Ansible

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, ansible

I am trying to setup Ansible playbook for tomcat application deployment. Apart from starting tomcat everything works without any issues. When i use startup.sh it works but i need to start tomcat with catalina.sh script.

```
   - name: start tomcat
     command: ./bin/catalina.sh start
     args:
       chdir: /websrv/tomcat/tomcat-8080/
```

This is what i am trying to do, it says started but it was never started.

```
TASK [start tomcat] ************************************************************
changed: [appserver.example.com]
```

Please help.

**Note**: I am using zipped version of tomcat on centos and have not installed tomcat. So if anyone shed light on how to start the script it would be really helpful.

Comment: @techraf JAVA_HOME is defined on catalina.sh script and it is not included in .bash_profile. So while invoking/executing catalina.sh JAVA_HOME will be exported to the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in Tomcat management scripts don't detach from the tty, which causes them to be killed when the Ansible ssh session ends. You need to either hack the script to cause it to be backgrounded/detached, or write and install a proper init/systemd script (or crib from any of the numerous examples out there) for Tomcat. For example, [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/tomcat-standalone/roles/tomcat/files/tomcat-initscript.sh) or [here](http://www.devopstutor.com/how-to-start-tomcat-using-ansible/) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible)...

Comment: Thanks Matt, I used [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/tomcat-standalone/roles/tomcat/files/tomcat-initscript.sh) script and modified as needed and it works fine now.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a quick solution to run tomcat server unattached from Ansible's TTY use the following:

```
- name: "Starting Apache server"
  command: nohup {{ apache_install_location }}/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  I tried Writing proper init/systemd script but although it worked manually, it did not work via ansible.

Good thing about the above approach is that the tomcat logs are directed to catalina.out instead of being written to nohup.out.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: tomcat-server
  service:
            name: tomcat
            state: started
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?