# How to run Tomcat using ansible

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. In my Ansible playbook, when I try to do the following:

```
- name: Start tomcat
  command: "/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"
```

On running playbook I see it running the task successfully, but when I try to check on target machine:

```
  ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

Tomcat is not running.

I have looked up SO questions like https://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible but not sure as to how it will work. I also get the script from https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/tomcat-standalone/roles/tomcat/files/tomcat-initscript.sh and try to run it as

```
- name: Start Tomcat
  script: /tmp/tomcat-initscript.sh
```

but doesnt help. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run tomcat catalina script on Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242051/how-to-run-tomcat-catalina-script-on-ansible)

Answer (score 4):

`tomcat-initscript.sh` is a SysV-style init-script; it takes commands.  So you might try

```
- name: start tomcat
  script: /tmp/tomcat-initscript.sh start
```

Ideally, you'll actually copy it across to your system (probably to `/etc/init.d`) so you can use the `service` module to interact with it.

Many Linux systems have switched to other init systems, so depending on your distro you may wish to write an upstart or systemd file instead (which are much simpler than SysV-style scripts).

Did you not install tomcat through your distro's package manager?  The package will almost certainly have included an init script already.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to use

```
command: nohup /tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried several options on a couple of Ubuntu VMs. Using the `startup.sh` works for me.

Here's a snippet of the task from my playbook

```
 - name: Start Tomcat
   command: "nohup /Path_To_Catalina_Home/bin/startup.sh"
   tags: startTomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nohup helped me out with making a tomcat upgrade script here since we still use shell scripts to control tomcat, thanks! I added ignore errors since my script also runs some validation.

```
  - name: Run a script to restart tomcat
    shell:  nohup /shared/path/app.sh restart
    ignore_errors: yes
```