# Shell command works manually, not using Ansible

Tags: bash, tomcat, ansible

I'm playing with Ansible (still learning), but I encountered a problem I can't think of a solution.

I'm trying to install and launch Tomcat on a remote server using Ansible.

The installation is working, but the last step which is the activation of the Tomcat server is failing.

If I manually launch the startup.sh script (as `su -`), using the following command : `bash /opt/tomcat/startup.sh`, I can see the tomcat homepage.

Using the ansible playbook I wrote, even though Ansible doesn't show up any errors, I can't see the tomcat homepage.

Here is the task I'm running :

```
   - name: Launch Tomcat
      command: bash /opt/tomcat/startup.sh
      become: true
```

I tried to add `become_user: root` and `become_method: sudo` with no success.

I think it may be related to how `become: true` is handled by ansible but I'm not sure.

Comment: first use -vvv in your ansible-playbook command for verbose output. In it you can see an extended output from your ansible plays.

Comment: See: [How to run tomcat catalina script on Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39242051/3776858)

Comment: There might be a problem with the environment. "sudo su" is different from "su -" where `-, -l, --login Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly`. Why don't you try [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-execute-shell-commands-on-targets): `su - && bash /opt/tomcat/startup.sh` without `become: true`? Make sure `remote_user` is the same whom the "su -" command works fine for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried using the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html)-module instead of the command-module?

> With the Command module the command will be executed without being proceeded through a shell. As a consequence some variables like $HOME are not available. And also stream operations like  <, >, | and & will not work.
>
> The Shell module runs a command through a shell, by default /bin/sh. This can be changed with the option executable. Piping and redirection are here therefor available.
> (Source: https://blog.confirm.ch/ansible-modules-shell-vs-command/)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the environment. "sudo su" is different from "su -" where

> -, -l, --login Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

Try [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-execute-shell-commands-on-targets) (because it allows pipes, redirection, logical operations, ...) without `become: true`

```
shell: su - && bash /opt/tomcat/startup.sh
```

Make sure *`remote_user`* is the same whom the *`su -`* command works fine for.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem while working with startup.sh in ansible script.i got to know the tomcat server process got starts but immediately shutdown as well.
so the solution to the problem is running or starting the tomcat server in nohup
thru ansible
Here is the sample script.

```
cat start.yml
---
- name: Playbook to stop server
  #hosts: localhost
  hosts: webserver

  tasks:
   - name: Start the server tomcat from UI
     shell:
              nohup /home/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start >> /home/tomcat/somelog
```